# Splitting array into multiple arrays alphabetically iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array it looks like

```
NSArray *array=@[@"apple",@"animal",@"ant",@"beat",@"bean".....];
```

I need to split into multiple arrays alphabetically

I am adding the piece of code what I tried

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH 'a'"];
  NSArray *aElements = [arrLastName filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

NSPredicate works good but at second line am getting an error
I dont need to solve this error . only thing is reformation the array into multiple arrays alphabatecilly

```
 Initializing 'NSArray *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Initializing 'NSArray *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused the `NSMutableArray` method `filterUsingPredicate` with the `NSArray` method `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`.  The former modifies the receiver `NSMutableArray` and returns void.  The latter leaves the original array unchanged and returns a new array.

So what you wanted is -

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH 'a'"];
NSArray *aElements = [arrLastName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

However this approach would require you to iterate the array multiple times. I would use the following approach -

```
 NSMutableDictionary *alphaArrays=[NSMutableDictionary new];
 for (NSString *word in arrLastName) {
    NSString *firstletter=[word substringToIndex:1];
    NSMutableArray *wordArray=alphaArrays[firstletter];
    if (wordArray == nil) {
       wordArray=[NSMutableArray new];
       alphaArrays[firstletter]=wordArray;
    }
    [wordArray addObject:word];
 }
```

Comment: It may be more efficient, however to simply iterate the array once, adding the elements to 1 of 26 mutable arrays as you go

Comment: error solved but primary thing is i need to split into another array alphabetically

Comment: Yes, using this technique you will need to create 26 predicates and each predicate will iterate the array.

Comment: yes but the array elements not fetching into new array , i am getting empty array

Comment: its adding all elements into array @paulw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71575/discussion-between-paulw11-and-cool-cracker).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `filterUsingPredicate:` it filters the `NSMutableArray` itself and it won't return anything (return type is `void`) .

You need to use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` (It returns a filtered `NSArray`)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH 'a'"];
NSArray *aElements     = [arrLastName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Check the [NSMutableArray Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/filterUsingPredicate:), you can see the methods declared like:

```
- (void)filterUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate

- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @midhun , your answer solved the error but still array elements not fetching into new array

Comment: @Coolcracker:  Check the predicate and also check the arrLastName contains any data. In your code you are populating `array` and using `arrLastName`.

Answer (score 1):

Using this library , it would be easy to solve LinqToObjectiveC https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC

This library has the following method groupBy https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#groupBy

```
   NSArray* input = @[@"James", @"Jim", @"Bob"];

   NSDictionary* groupedByFirstLetter = [input linq_groupBy:^id(id name) {
           return [name substringToIndex:1];
    }];

 // the returned dictionary is as follows:
has two keys "J" and "B" and corresponding arrays as values
 // {
   //     J = ("James", "Jim"); - First Array 
   //     B = ("Bob"); - Second Array
 // }
```